# Difficulty reading 2D character array variable from netcdf file in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, character, netcdf4

I have the following fortran code for reading a two-dimensional character array variable:

```
program read_metar_station_from_rec
   use netcdf
   implicit none

  ! This is the name of the data file we will create.
   character (len = *), parameter :: FILE_NAME = "metar.nc"

   character (len = *), parameter :: STA_NAME = "stationName"
   integer, dimension(nf90_max_var_dims) :: dimIDs
   integer :: ncid
   integer :: nRecords,maxStaNamLen
   integer :: station_varid
   integer :: i,j
   character, allocatable :: stations(:,:)

  ! Create the netCDF file. The nf90_clobber parameter tells netCDF to
  ! overwrite this file, if it already exists.
  ! Open the file. 
  call check( nf90_open(FILE_NAME, nf90_nowrite, ncid) )

  ! Get the varid of stationName.
  call check( nf90_inq_varid(ncid, STA_NAME, station_varid) )

  ! Get dimensions of stationName.
  call check( nf90_inquire_variable(ncid, station_varid, dimids = dimIDs))
  call check( nf90_Inquire_Dimension(ncid, dimIDs(1), len = maxStaNamLen))
  call check( nf90_Inquire_Dimension(ncid, dimIDs(2), len = nRecords) )

  allocate(stations(maxStaNamLen,nRecords))
  call check( nf90_get_var(ncid, station_varid, stations) )
  do i=1,maxStaNamLen
    do j=1,100
        print *, stations(i,j)
    enddo
  enddo
  ! Close the file. This frees up any internal netCDF resources
  ! associated with the file, and flushes any buffers.
  call check( nf90_close(ncid) )

  print *, "*** SUCCESS reading example file metar.nc! "

contains
  subroutine check(status)
    integer, intent ( in) :: status

    if(status /= nf90_noerr) then 
      print *, trim(nf90_strerror(status))
      stop "Stopped"
    end if
  end subroutine check  
end program read_metar_station_from_rec
```

The issue I am facing is that, suppose I try to print the first 5 records then I see only 5 characters as shown in below image:

[image: program output]
If I increase the number of records, then I see the same 5 characters but more empty lines between them. The actual entries of the stationName variable looks like this in python:
[image: variable to be read]

I am herewith attaching a link to the data that I am trying to read:
[netcdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KEYYi7R1cBTgU1xFVX3qk5K3gc4Ok0sB/view?usp=sharing)

Please let me know if the question isn't clear.

Comment: This: `allocate(stations(maxStaNamLen,nRecords))` surprises me, I'd have expected `allocate(stations(nRecords,maxStaNamLen))`, i.e. one row in the array for each station name, one column for each station name letter.  But maybe I have misunderstood your code.

Comment: I'm not sure it is related, but I recalled [this](https://github.com/thehackerwithin/PyTrieste/wiki/F2Py#example-2-passing-array-arguments) when I saw your problem... As Fortran arrays are [_column-major_](http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#multidimensional-arrays), you should probably iterating through `j = 1, 100` in the outer loop and `i = 1, maxStaNamLen` in the inner loop.